# amend and save existing analytics report

Tags: google-analytics, save, analytics

It seems that since last week the Save and Email options have moved or disappeared from existing analytics reports - I can access my reports from customisation but cannot work out how to save my changes. Where are these options please?

Comment: Hi, make sure to follow the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . For instance, what software are you talking about, etc.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to Google analytics reports, the Email and Save features are still here. The links have just been moved to the top right-hand corner of the reports. You will find the Email feature when clicking on `Share`.

Cf screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Elaine Sage Does this answer to your question?